# JQUERY slidetoggle isn't working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, toggle, slide

I don't understand why jquery script isn't working.
Here is sample:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#mygtukas-js').click(function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
      });

      if($('#mygtukas-js').data('clicked')){
        $(this).next('#turinys').slideToggle(500);
      }
      else {
        $('#turinys').hide();
      }
  });
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5NmK9/

Comment: What do you mean with "isn't working"?

Comment: My div doesn't sliding. :(

Comment: can you post the full code to jsfiddle.net and reproduce the bug?

Answer (score 1):

Your slideToggle block is called once, on document.ready. When you click on #mygtukas-js, it changes 'clicked' to true, but it doesn't call the if/else block.

You should have the if/else block be within the code called after click, or have it within its own event listener.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mygtukas-js').on("click", function() {
        // The line below can be removed if you're not using the data
        // value anywhere else.
        $(this).data('clicked', true);

        $(this).next('#turinys').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

The `.slideToggle()` will do the show/hide.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5NmK9/1/

Comment: I would add that it might make sense to ditch the 'clicked' value, unless it's used elsewhere. A simple slideToggle will keep track of the state.

Comment: @MikeManfrin exactly.